# Sharing on Linkedin get error code 403

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I try to share something on LinkedIn but there I'm getting a `403` error:

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

The complete error message:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1470445923681,
  "message": "Access to posting shares denied",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "status": 403,
  "requestId": "O27PVSHUCY"
}
```

Here is my sharing message (you can past it to [JSON Editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) for easier view):

```
{ 
   "comment":"Hello",   
   "visibility":{       
       "code":"anyone"   
   },   
   "content":{       
       "title":"Android LinkedIn Integration/Login and Make User Profile",      
       "description":"Login Integration with LinkedIn",      
       "submitted-url":"https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-linkedin-integrationlogin-and-make-userprofile",      
       "submitted-image-url":"https://www.numetriclabz.com/?attachment_id=11320"   
   }
}
```

Here is the Scope:

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE);
}
```

Here is my configuration on my LinkedIn:

[image: LinkedIn Configuration]

I am able to login and get user profile, so the hash key is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out the solution, it is quite simple. We need to uninstall everything (include the LinkedIn app) from our mobile and re-install it again, then everything will be fine.

I think their is something conflict between the application and the LinkedIn app.

Thank you for your concern. Hope it may help for the other guys.